# How to set a login page to see the website in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

i'm a beginner and I'm trying to set a login page on my website build in wordpress. Searching on google I don't find a solution for my issue. There are a lot of plugins that customize the login page in wp-admin to acces at the backend. What I'm trying to do is different. I'd like to put a login page at my website www.example.com (home page) and after the user has insered the credentials, he can see everything on the website. I don't know how to start. Every suggests are appreciate. Thank you in advance

Comment: So you want like a paywall?

Comment: I'd like that all website is restrict. After a login the user can see everithing on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're ok with using WP users table and auth systems you could put template content inside a conditional to check if users are logged in.

It isn't elegant but it would get you what you want.